# Кеширование сайта

Tags: php, header, кэширование, pagespeed-insights

Есть сайт. Его проверка в Google PageSpeed даёт результат 70/100 при этом ругается на отсутствие кеширования. В файл index.php перед генерацией страницы вставил вот такие строки:

```
header("cache-control: private, max-age = 7200, s-maxage = 7200");
header("last-modified: ".gmdate("d, d m y h:i:s")." gmt");
```

При этом во время загрузки в браузере в панели разработчика на вкладке Network вижу что эти заголовки отрабатывают и действительно отправляются в том виде в котором я указал, а многие загружаемые файлы действительно подгружаются из кеша, но почему-то Google PageSpeed всё так и ругается на кеширование как будто я не использую эти заголовки. Как можно убедить Google PageSpeed что я использую кеширование?

Comment: Кэширование страницы или кэширование статических файлов? Это таки разные вещи

Comment: Кэширование статических файлов, действительно, будет правильнее. Прошу меня простить. В этом вопросе я полный ноль)

Comment: А кэширование статических файлов прописывается где-то в настройках веб-сервера, а не в php

Comment: GooglePageSpeed вроде пишет как лучше всего исправить ошибки. Там ссылки разные в тексте ошибок (сам пользовался им 3 года назад, может сейчас что-то поменялось)

Comment: Он пишет что нужно использовать заголовки cache-control и last-modified. В этом и проблема - я их итак использую, но сервис просит чтобы я их использовал. Поэтому и задаю вопрос - что я делаю не так

Comment: Он действительно просит кешировать результат index.php ? Очень странно, и совсем не всегда это правильно. Может, все-таки речь идет о статических файлах?

Answer (score 2):

Я кэишировал через файл .htaccess

```
<filesmatch "\.(jpg|gif|png|css|js|ico)$">
    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
</filesmatch>
```

также включал кэширование самим браузером и рекомендуемое GZIP сжатие через .htaccess

```
<ifModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml application/xml application/xhtml+xml text/javascript text/css application/javascript application/x-javascript
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4.0[678] no-gzip
    BrowserMatch bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
</ifModule>
```

Comment: я и сам делал примерно так, но на сервере используется nginx, следовательно htaccess не работает